# What could be the reason for suddenly changing brightness in raw image?

Tags: raw, sensor, brightness

A series of night shots show this abrupt change of brightness:
It starts at approximately 60% horizontal and extends to the right corner.

I didn't notice this effect before, the temperature was around 32°F (0°C).

In daylight this doesn't happen what could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: This would be an indication of the shutter sticking as it travels.

Comment: @MikeDixon Thanks for this idea, the shutter moves vertical the effect described is horizontal.

Comment: What is the specific camera in question?

Comment: @MichaelC Sony A7RII with Tamron 70-300 (with Canon Adaptor)

Comment: Possibly the bright red beam. if it rotated, suddenly hit the lens and caused the diaphragm to stop down.

Comment: Are there any filters on the front of your lens?

Comment: @MichaelC No filter was attached

Answer (score 2):

I suspect **you are shooting through a window** and the difference in brightness is caused by the reflection of a curtain or vertical blinds.

[image: reflection]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the shots were made outdoor.  But it could be that a light source was partially blocked by a steel construction.

Comment: If I think of anything else, I'll revise my answer.